# Simple question for Selenium 'find_element_by_XPath'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am very new to Python and I would like to try to do a bank automation for below credentials:

https://olb.ccb.com/CCBIS/V6/STY4/B5/login_hk.jsp

[image]

I try to use below code to send login ID to the screen but it says the below error:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/input').send_keys('abcd_1234')
```

[image]

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
> element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/form[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4Rq2.png)/div/table/tbody/tr[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvA64.png)/td/div/input"}

Does anyone can help me how to send key to the input?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have check the website and i find that the problem it not only because of your xpath.
The login is put in another iframe. So you need to switch to that iframe in order to send key to login and password field.Also you should using id instead of absolute xpath.
Try the following code. I have tested it so it should work.

```
    driver.get("https://olb.ccb.com/CCBIS/V6/STY4/EN/login_hk.jsp")
    iframe = driver.find_element_by_id("fclogin")
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_id("USERID").send_keys("admin")
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_id("LOGPASS").send_keys("admin")
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The more ideal way would be this if your more concerned about stability and speed by using webdriver waits.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://olb.ccb.com/CCBIS/V6/STY4/EN/login_hk.jsp")
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "fclogin")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "USERID"))).send_keys("admin")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "LOGPASS"))).send_keys("admin")
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following XPATH instead:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//INPUT[@id='USERID']").send_keys("abcd_1234")`